# How to associate an id from a select form with another object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, associations, nested-forms, form-helpers

I have two models: `Study` and `StudyType`. The later has just two columns: `id` and `name` and stores the type of a study like *Bachelor*, *Master* and so on. All values are inserted already. I used the command `rake db:seed` after add the appropriate statements to `/db/seeds.rb`.
The `StudyType` `has_many :studies` where as the `Study` `belongs_to :study_type` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :study_type`.

Now I want a **select field** in my new-study-form. I created the select field (see below) but when I submit the form the form **inserts a new entry in the `study_types` table**?!? instead of setting the `id` of the `study_type` in the `study` object. Can you help me?

Here is the `new` action of the `studies_controller`

```
@study = Study.new
...
@study.study_type = StudyType.new
```

Here is the study partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "shared/study_form_fields", :locals => { :study_fields => study_fields } %>  
...
<%= study_fields.fields_for :subject_type do |study_type_fields| %>
  <%= render :partial => "shared/study_type_form_fields", :locals => { :study_type_fields => study_type_fields } %>
<% end %><!-- End of study_type_fields -->
...
```

Here is the study_type partial.

```
# File: _study_type_form_fields.html.erb
<%= study_type_fields.label :name, "Study type" %>
<%= study_type_fields.collection_select :name, StudyType.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please select a study type." %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should you need to use `study_type_id` instead of `name` here

```
# File: _study_type_form_fields.html.erb
<%= study_type_fields.label :study_type_id, "Study type" %>
<%= study_type_fields.collection_select :study_type_id, StudyType.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please select a study type." %>
```